# How to add http:// to a string if the string does not contain it?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know how to add `http://` to a string, by checking beforehand if it's already in the string or not.

How can I efficiently transform a string into a full url using only javascript (perhaps with regular expressions)? Ideally I can check to see if the string ends in .com/.org/.net etc too.

Comment: Your question does not show how you tried to solve this yourself.

Comment: Your question is unclear. *What* would not exist?

Comment: @PointedEars: The fact he could not write his thoughts correctly made me lose points for nothing. lol.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but please go over [this](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) and [this](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) before copy-pasting any of the answers below in your code.

Comment: @adrianp The “Google JavaScript Style Guide” that you referred (never use “this” and the like for link texts) is outdated; some items are even questionable, limiting the developer in unnecessary ways without good reason. Crockford's rules and jslint … you don't want to get me started on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var reg = /^((http|https|ftp)://)/;

if(!reg.test(your_url)) { your_url = "http://" + your_url; }
```

Comment: Nice, testing for https and ftp, too... but, eh, `url` would have no value is the if block isn't hit, right? Maybe change `url` to `your_url`?

Comment: The point of the one-line `if` being? Use the ternary if you insist.

Comment: @thejh You are right!

Comment: you need to escape the slashes so regex should be var reg = /^((http|https|ftp):\/\/)/;

Answer (score 3):

You can use indexOf to check http://

```
if(str.indexOf("http://") < 0){
   str = "http://" + str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use **String concatenation**:

```
/* s being the string */
if(s.substr(0,7) !== "http://")
    s = "http://"+s;
```

Comment: -1 – Let me quote from the title: "if it doesn't exist"

Comment: I fail to see how this answer is necessarily wrong. The question is completely and totally unclear.

Comment: @thejh Edited (after reading between the lines since the question is damn unclear). Could you explain the -1 again now?

Comment: @Ghillied: Apart from the missing indent in the last line, no objections. But my vote is locked in – maybe vote lock-in is not removed if an edit happens in the first five minutes or so? Edit: Yes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62219/cannot-retract-downvote-if-post-has-been-edited-within-first-5-minutes-of-postin

Comment: @thejh Ah, it's okay I guess. Thanks for coming back though.

Answer (score 1):

Adapt to your needs

```
<script>
var url = "http://www.google.com..."; 
var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/

if (regexp.test(url)) {
    alert(url);
} else {
    alert('http://' + url);
}
</script>
```

Comment: coding style comment: you're mixing semicolon-terminated and non-semicolon-terminated lines